# @Async in SpringBoot creating new thread but Controller waits for async call to finish before sending a response back

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-aop

**Context**

I've a scenario - I need to expose a rest endpoint and provide a post method , which will be used by a fronend to receive form values (name, email, address).
With these details I need ti call a third party api (that could take upto 10 seconds to respond).
Additionally , I need to store the processed application and the response in DB somewhere to keep a track for monitoring purposes.

**Problem**
I plan to use Spring `@Async` functionality for storing details in Queue (the a DB) so that I dont keep the user waiting for response while I do this storing. The `@Async` seems to be creating new Thread , I can see from the logs but Controller doesn’t send the response back to client (Which is contrary to actual `@Async` knowledge I have which is not alot) ; So, until the async completes user has to wait for the response.

Is there anything wrong here or missing ?

TIA for your help.

here are some snippets of my classes-

**Main**

```
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class CardsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CardsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@Validated
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CardEligibilityController {
    private final CardEligibilityService cardEligibilityService;

    @PostMapping("/check-eligibility")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    public EligibilityResponse checkEligibility(@RequestBody @Valid Applicant applicant){
        return cardEligibilityService.eligibilityService(applicant);
    }
}
```

**Service 1**

```
public interface CardEligibilityService {
    EligibilityResponse eligibilityService(Applicant applicant);
}

@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CardEligibilityServiceImpl implements CardEligibilityService {

    private final ThirdPartyEligibilityAdapter thirdPartyEligibilityAdapter;
    private final QueueService queueService;
    private final QueueMessageResponseService queueMessageResponseService;

    @Override
    public EligibilityResponse eligibilityService(Applicant applicant){
        EligibilityResponse eligibilityResponse = checkEligibility(applicant);
        queueService.pushMessage(queueMessageResponseService.createQueueResponse(applicant,eligibilityResponse));
        return eligibilityResponse;
    }

    private EligibilityResponse checkEligibility(Applicant applicant) {
        return thirdPartyEligibilityAdapter.getEligibility(applicant);
    }

}
```

**Service 2**

```
public interface QueueService {
     void pushMessage(QueueMessage queueMessage);
     void retry();
}


@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class QueueServiceImpl implements QueueService{

    private final List<QueueMessage> deadQueue = new LinkedList<>();


    //TODO check why async gets response stuck
    @Override
    @Async
    public void pushMessage(QueueMessage queueMessage){
        try {
            //Push message to a queue - Queue settings Rabbit/Kafka - then this could be
            //used by listeners to persist the data into DB
            log.info("message queued {} ", queueMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error {} , queueMessage {} ", e, queueMessage);
            deadQueue.add(queueMessage);
        }
    }

   
**This method is a fault tolerance mechanism in case push to queue had any issues, The Local Method call to pushMessage isn’t the problem I also tried this by deleting retry method method**

    @Override
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000)
    public void retry() {
        log.info("Retrying Message push if there are any failure in enqueueing ");
        final List<QueueMessage> temp = new LinkedList<>(deadQueue);
        deadQueue.clear();
        Collections.reverse(temp);
        temp.forEach(this::pushMessage);
    }

}
```

**Service 3**

```
public interface QueueMessageResponseService {
    QueueMessage createQueueResponse(Applicant applicant, EligibilityResponse eligibilityResponse);
}

@Service
public class QueueMessageResponseServiceServiceImpl implements QueueMessageResponseService {
    @Override
    public QueueMessage createQueueResponse(Applicant applicant, EligibilityResponse eligibilityResponse) {
        return new QueueMessage(applicant,eligibilityResponse);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

**THE MOST STRANGE BEHAVIOUR**

If I add `Thread.sleep(20);` in my async method, This works as expected , the user gets a response back without waiting for `async` to complete. But Still unable to understand the cause.

```
@Async
    public void pushMessage(QueueMessage queueMessage) {
        try {
            //Push message to a queue - Queue settings Rabbit/Kafka - then this could be
            //used by listeners to persist the data into DB
            Thread.sleep(20);
            log.info("message queued {} ", queueMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error {} , queueMessage {} ", e, queueMessage);
            deadQueue.add(queueMessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You tagged this question by `spring-aop`, which is how I found it. Where is your aspect code?

Comment: @kriegaex Actually I've put aop as the @ EnableAsync internally uses AOP to create proxies. Apologies if it's a wrong tag. I could remove it if it causes confusion.

Comment: No, I was just wondering and thus asking. Thanks for the reply. I just know now that I am out of here, because I probably cannot contribute to a solution, being an AOP expert but by no means a general Spring expert.

Answer (score 3):

The call to `pushMessage` in `retry` is a LOCAL call. So the proxy is not involved an the method is executed synchronously.

You have to move the async method to it's own class.

Comment: Thanks @Simon , The actual call is from Service1(CardEligibilityServiceImpl). The call from retry is just a fault tolerance mechanism. The current problem is usual call from CardEligibilityServiceImpl which isn't working, I also tried this by deleting retry method.

Comment: Ah I see. What does createQueueResponse do?

Comment: It just collates Applicant and Response in a single object in QueueMessage(Pojo). Which in turn will be saved to the Queue. I have added that service as well now.

Comment: You are logging in the async method. Which task is printed in the conolse?

Comment: The worker thread  "2021-05-06 11:45:53.836  INFO 7364 --- [         task-1] QueueServiceImpl       : message queued QueueMessage(applicant=Applicant(name=Angela, address=aaa, email=aa@a.com), eligibilityResponse=EligibilityResponse(eligibleCards=[C1, C2])) 
"

Comment: Just a wild guess @EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true) remove proxyTargetClass = true

Comment: Still No Luck !! :/